# Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it). Here have to add that flag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, async-await, craco

```
const { addAfterLoader, loaderByName } = require("@craco/craco");

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure(webpackConfig) {
      addAfterLoader(webpackConfig, loaderByName("babel-loader"), {
        test: /\.mdx?$/,
        loader: require.resolve("@mdx-js/loader"),
      });
      return webpackConfig;
    },
  },
};
```

Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
- ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js

Where I have to add `topLevelAwait` this flag in between these codes.

Comment: Per [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#enabling),  top level await has been enabled since version 14.8.0, and the current and latest LTS versions of node are  v18.1.0  [ref](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) as of today. However, top level `await` is only available in ES6 modules and not in CommonJS modules. Hence can you provide the version of node in use and confirm that the main module is in fact an ES6 module? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using Node v18.12.1